# Can JavaScript files be used in Android?

Tags: java, javascript, android

I need to add some JavaScript code to my program. Is it possible to add `.js` files in Android?
    If so, can you tell me the way how to do it, and extract the codes.

Comment: do you want to add that in webview??

Comment: no not in webview,
i have daynightoverlay.js file using that i need to create a image of daynightoverlay

Comment: then where you want to add??

Comment: i need to generate a image like the image in the link
[link](timeanddate.com/worldclock/sunearth.html)

so i'm having daynightoverlay.js file and need to add it

Comment: i think its a webview image you want to generate..

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is "42".

Comment: @Prag's Thank you 
I'll try to get the image in web view itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Phonegap** it will be usefull

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Comment: Giving a little more information than just posting a link would be great as this answer doesn't meet the standards of this site. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes.Using `Phonegap` you can use JS files in android.

Here is the link to get you started.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the link
i'm not going to use it in webview
any how i'll try this too

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/353661/Writing-Android-Programs-with-HTML-and-JavaScrip

You can refer this to implement codarva...

Answer (score 0):

Or if your app is primitive you just can use `WebView`

Comment: I'm not going to add it in webview

Comment: Okay, try use 'apache cordova'

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** use Js Files directly into android. Instead use Codarva or else phonegap to have the Js files

Answer (score 0):

[Android - Loading an external .js file into a webview then accessing it's functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971832/android-loading-an-external-js-file-into-a-webview-then-accessing-its-functi)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/353661/Writing-Android-Programs-with-HTML-and-JavaScrip